# Displaying a data saved successfully message in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 4.

I am trying to Toggle a div or p tag on the basis of a condition.
I got the answer to display the tags using tempdata like so,in the Index Action Method of Home Controller

```
@if (TempData["notice"] != null) {
            <p id="para">@TempData["notice"]</p>
```

I am setting the Tempdata in another Action Method of another controller

```
TempData["notice"] = "Successfully registered";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Once the control is sent back tothe index method,the paragraph is displayed correctly.
I was wondering ,if there was a way to hide it now.

I know,we can use

```
document.getElementById('para').style.display = "none";
```

If I use this,I wont be able to see the para even after redirect.
Kindly guide me in the right direction.

Comment: [jQuery hide method](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [jQuery delay method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: I dont want it to be displayed the first time I come to the page.Its only after the redirect,it should be displayed and get hidden a few seconds after.

Comment: I am trying to simulate a success message after data has been added to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) methods. Code below hides your message with delay in 2 seconds (`.delay(2000)`)

```
@if(TempData["notice"] != null) {
   <p id="para">@TempData["notice"]</p>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      $('#para').delay(2000).hide(500);
   });
</script>
```